# How to model a fluid like object without particle system or fluid simulation

Tags: modeling

What I had in mind is something like this: [image]

[image]

Now I know it probably can be done with particle system and metaballs (something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0Tz1U6A5vI) ) or fluid simulation.

Thing is that in order to do it with metaballs you need a quite powerful PC to handle all the polygons and same thing with fluid simulation ( and I also have 0 experience when it comes to fluids sim). Is there a way to make object like in images with bend modifier or even maybe sculpting, any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a displacement modifier with a texture.

I tried using a clouds texture and a stucci texture, which came up with a decent result. Didn't look to much like the image, but if you have a better base mesh, and just keep messing around with adding more textures, and adjusting size and strength, you should be able to come up with a good answer.

p.s. you need to add another displacement modifier for each new texture you add.

Comment: But what texture should I use?

Comment: well, I was coming up with a similar effect, but got my own problem.  I was trying to render with my GPU, and it crashes when I try to render.  Immediately.  Not just the render, but the whole program.  I have a geforce gtx 750, so this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: but I was using a clouds texture and a stucci texture.  Came up with a decent result.  Didn't look to much like the image, but if you have a better base mesh, and just keep messing around with adding more textures, and adjusting size and strength, you should be able to come up with a good answer.

Comment: p.s.  you need to add another displacement modifier for each new texture you add.